# Undesired behavior while making loop menu

Tags: c, recursion, switch-statement, do-while

as the title suggests, I've tried making a sort-of interactive menu in two ways: one with a loop and the other by making a recursive function. Either way yields the same behaviour, that is, it "takes" my first input as the one for when it should be *asked* upon calling.

To better explain it, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void goback(int *flag)
{
    char selector;

    printf("Do you want to return to menu?\n1. Yes\n2. No\n");
    selector=getchar();
    printf("\n");

    switch(selector)
    {
        case '1':
            break;
        case '2':
            *flag=1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
            goback(flag);
    }

}
int main()
{
    char select;
    int flag=0;

    do
    {
        printf("Main menu\n\n");
        printf("1. A\n2. Exit\n\n");
        scanf("%c", &select);
        switch(select)
        {
            case '1':
            //execute code here and ask the user if they want to go back
            //to the main menu
                goback(&flag);
                break;
            case '2':
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input option!\n\n");
        }
    }while(select!='2' && flag==0);

    return 0;
}
```

Either of the two functions *will* have as an ouput the message that is printed should the user input a *non-valid* option, followed by a second iteration of whichever; why it takes the prior input when it is called either function?

Comment: This is an easy trap to fall into. The second call to `scanf` picks up newline character. I am sure there is a duplicate in SO.

Comment: In that case pardon, I've come across some similar but not the ones I was looking for.

Edit: In that case, what should be the proper way to avoid this? I was thinking of reading the newline character after executing what's inside the options.

Comment: That's ok. It's not always easy to find a question in SO that addresses the problem you are having.

Comment: Hmm, after reading the post you linked to, would it work if instead I read the newline outside of the switch?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks! Lastly, is better to make this sort of menus with a loop or is fine if I do it recursively like in goback(int *flag)?